# Calculate Income Tax amount of UK Salary

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, salary, calculation

I've recently been trying to calculate different take home amounts from different salaries, and have ended up getting confused over how the different tax brackets work. If I try to calculate the amount for a salary below the higher tax bracket (£35k - 40%), then I don't have any troubles, so I'm assuming I'm misunderstanding what happens exactly after this, and further, tax brackets.

#### Simple example

Working out take-home amount for £45,000.

Currently, [UK Income Tax rates](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/rates/it.htm) are:

```
£0 - £7,475         0%  
£7,476 - £35,000    20%  
£35,001 - £150,000  40%  
£150,000+           50%
```

So, from what I know, on a £45,000 salary:

```
(45,000 - 35,000) * 0.4
    = 4000
(35,000 - 7475) * 0.2
    = 27525 * 0.2 = 5505
```

Meaning `£9,505` to be taken off as tax. Correct?

But when I use [The Salary Calculator](http://www.thesalarycalculator.co.uk/salary.php) site, it tells me that £8,010 is income tax.

Can anyone tell me **what the correct figure should be**, and **where I'm going wrong** in my calculations? Also, if you could point me in the direction of some decent tutorials/articles on this sort of stuff, that would be most welcome!

Comment: Your math looks right to me...

Comment: Nevermind, Ganesh Sittampalam nailed it in his answer.

Comment: Wow, thanks for sharing the UK tax brackets. It gives a great perspective on the US tax brackets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The taxable bands are on top of the personal allowance (though by the 50% band, the personal allowance has reduced to 0 so there's no difference).

So the right calculation is

```
(45000 - 42475) * 0.4
    = 1010
(42475 - 7475) * 0.2
    = 7000
```

making `£8,010` as expected.

Comment: So at the 50% band, if working out for £200,000, the calculation would be: (200000 - 192475) * 0.5? Or (200000 - 157475) * 0.5? I'm not sure what you mean by the personal allowance being reduced to 0...

Comment: No, (200000 - 150000) * 0.5. The bands are on top of the personal allowance, but not cumulative. If you check footnote 1 in the HMRC link you gave, it describes how the personal allowance is reduced for income over 100K. The actual impact of this is that there's a band from 100-115K where the real marginal tax rate is 60%, but they don't present it that way.

Comment: Aaahhh, I see. Thanks for the explanation - seems a lot more complicated than it should be at first, but it makes sense now. Thanks.