# What's the correct formula to calculate my monthly wage (deducting UK Income Tax and National Insurance)?

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, calculation, financial-literacy

For a given salary, how do I work out what would be paid into my bank each month?

The Income Tax part is explained for the main part in [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/8450/calculate-income-tax-amount-of-uk-salary), but I can't make sense of the National Insurance part. The sources I can find all site weekly pay!

Answer (score 3):

http://listentotaxman.com/ has a great calculator that gives you the results in yearly, monthly and weekly wage.

Answer (score 3):

Most employees will be in NI category A.  In the 2015/16 tax year a category A employee paid monthly pays:

0% on earnings below £672/month
12% on earnings from £672 to £3532/month
2% on earnings above £3532/month

[Source](https://www.gov.uk/national-insurance-rates-letters/contribution-rates)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.thesalarycalculator.co.uk/salary.php is also good, and pretty much identical to the listentotaxman one (with slightly less detail). I just prefer the colour scheme.