# How are national insurance deductions calculated in the UK?

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, salary, national-insurance

I understand that in the UK national insurance is a deduction made to your salary. I have seen [this question/answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/10875/whats-the-correct-formula-to-calculate-my-monthly-wage-deducting-uk-income-tax), that lists 2 very good websites that breakdown your take home pay for UK residents.

However, TAX has some clear guidlines, i.e. £10K tax free, 20% on earnings between £10K and £41K, and so on. Is there some guidelines like that for National Insurance?

Answer (score 6):

To quote from the [HMRC website](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/ni/intro/basics.htm):

> If you're employed you pay Class 1 National Insurance contributions. The rates are:
>
> if you earn more than £153 a week and up to £805 a week, you pay 12% of the amount you earn between £153 and £805
>
> if you earn more than £805 a week, you also pay 2% of all your earnings over £805
>
> You pay a lower rate if you're a member of your employer's contracted-out pension scheme.

If you're self-employed then it's much more complicated.